# Why do I use Time.deltaTime twice in this code?

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
void FixedUpdate()
{   
    //for gravity
    //
    buildingVelocity += gravityScale * Physics2D.gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    Vector2 deltaPosition = buildingVelocity * Time.deltaTime;

    Vector2 moveAmount = Vector2.up * deltaPosition.y;
    Moving (moveAmount);
    //
    //
}


//for gravity
//
void Moving(Vector2 moveAmount)
{
    rb2d.position += moveAmount;
}
```

I'm creating gravity for my game, following along with a Unity tutorial. I can account for all the decisions they've made, except one. I just don't understand why do I need the deltaPosition Vector2? Is it because I need to multiply again by Time.deltaTime? And if so, why? My simple mind says well... if deltaPosition = buildingVelocity... I'll just make Vector2 moveAmount = Vector2.up * buildingVelocity.y; and not even have to create the deltaPosition variable. Can someone break this down for me? why do I multiply it twice by deltatime? Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't look correct. Acceleration is an increase of velocity over time. You are already increasing the velocity over time with `buildingVelocity +=` so there is no need to again multiply by time. This would result in an increasing acceleration when gravity is a constant acceleration.

Comment: You have to do it the way it's coded.. It only works if you multiply by deltaTime twice like the code above, if anyone else understands why please let me know.